# A Morse Conundrum

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

Yesterday, I intercepted a message encoded in Morse code, but, because I was extremely tired, decided to wait until today to decode it to plain text. However, when I looked at the piece of paper I had written it on, I could not make heads nor tail of what I had written.

I know that the square is a dot, the dash is a dash, and the slash is the break character (used both between characters and between words).

For instance, look at the first two characters on the second line: they are both break characters, which you would never find two of in a row - even if it's between words, there would only be one. Then, the final row has seven non-break characters in a row, whereas the longest letter or number only uses five.

[image: The Morse code I had written down, visible in text form below.]

Can you decipher the message?

```
\.-.-\.
\\-\-.\
\--\-.\
\-\\.\.
.\\..--
.\..--\
.-.--..
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Oops, looks like you

> got your notes rotated.

So it should look like this:

> [image]

Which means the message is:

> **written on an angle**! (in both senses)

Comment: Do we need a rot13(qvntbany-guvaxvat) tag? `:)`

Comment: Bingo! Guess it was too easy.

Comment: @ZanyG Great puzzle nonetheless, and great answer Alconja! $(+1)$ to each of you :D